# How can I use mysql_multi_query in php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli-multi-query

```
<?php 
include "../../settings.php";  
include "$basepath/includes/conn.php"; 

/*$receiptnum='';*/ 
$submittedby=''; 
$statementno=''; 
$amount=''; 
$accno=''; 
$dateofpayment='';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { /*$receiptnum=$_POST['receiptnum'];   */   
    $statementno=$_POST['statementno']; $amount=$_POST['amount'];   
    $accno=$_REQUEST['accountnum']; $submittedby=$_POST['submitby'];   
    $dateofpayment=$_REQUEST['dateofpayment']; }
    /*$query= "CALL newreceipt('$reciptnum','$statementno','$amount',@doj1,'$accno','$submitedby')";*/ 
    $query="INSERT into statement(statementno) VALUES('".$statementno."')"; 
    $query.="INSERT into   
          receipt(statementno,accountnum,dateofpayment,amount,submittedby)   
          VALUES('".$statementno."','".$accno."','".$dateofpayment."','".$amount."','".$submittedby."')";
    $result=mysqli_multi_query($con,$query); {  
    if($result) { 
         die ("An unexpected error , Please try again!");           
    } else {
         header('Location: receipt.php');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: No, i wont format this properly. Do it yourself, then we may be - or better said might be able to help you.

Comment: format your question, buddy!, its not at all readable

Comment: fix this please it hurts my eyes!

Comment: ok i will re post with proper formate.

Comment: Can you please explain what is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php), you have 2 ways to do it. Since you are not using the object oriented way, I'll nearly-copy-paste an example (from the doc, as I said) of the procedural way:

```
// Your queries
$query="INSERT into statement(statementno) VALUES('".$statementno."')"; 
    $query.="INSERT into   
          receipt(statementno,accountnum,dateofpayment,amount,submittedby)   
          VALUES('".$statementno."','".$accno."','".$dateofpayment."','".$amount."','".$submittedby."')";

/* execute multi query */
if (mysqli_multi_query($con, $query)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = mysqli_store_result($con)) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
                printf("%s\n", $row[0]); // Or whatever...
            }
            mysqli_free_result($result); // Free in order to store the next
        }
        }
    } while (mysqli_next_result($con));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to insert those two separately? Also, take a look to mysqli_commit: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php This way you can avoid `multi_queries`. Look at the `Procedural style` example.

Comment: my code is perfect but it's redirect to another page but without inserting any value....

Comment: You cannot say "my code is perfect but is not inserting anything". Also, you have `if($result) { die (...); }`, it should be `if(!$result) { die (...); }`. So you have at least 1 error.